# GLFW doesn't detect half of the keys

Tags: java, lwjgl, fedora, glfw

Following code does work in case of space key and letters:

```
if (Input.keys_pressed[GLFW_KEY_SPACE])
    {
        this.bnumber = (this.bnumber + 1) % 5;
        Input.keys_pressed[GLFW_KEY_SPACE] = false;
    }
```

But don't react for any arrow, shifts, enter, delete, escape keys for example:

```
if (Input.keys_pressed[GLFW_KEY_UP])
    {
        this.bnumber = (this.bnumber + 1) % 5;
        Input.keys_pressed[GLFW_KEY_UP] = false;
    }
```

doesn't work at all. Do you know how to fix it?

I'm using lwjgl on Fedora 31.

Callback class:

```
public class Input extends GLFWKeyCallback {
public static boolean[] keys_pressed = new boolean[65536];
public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    keys_pressed[abs(key)] = action != GLFW.GLFW_RELEASE;

}}
```

And it is used this way in code:

```
glfwSetKeyCallback(this.window, new Input());
```

EDIT:
Page up and page down keys don't work as well.

EDIT2:
Actually only letters and space work.

Comment: keys_pressed[abs(key)] what is abs()? is it just absolute value? If so why are you taking the absolute value?

Comment: Because if more than one key is pressed at the same time the code seemed to be negative

Comment: That should not happen....